# How to change programatically added constraint for UIButton

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout

I have added constraint for UIButton in code:

```
topBtn.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  topBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 50)
])
```

Later, if I click some button, I want this constraint remove and change it to

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  topBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view2.topAnchor, constant: 50)
])
```

How to achieve this? I have tried

```
NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([
  topBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 50)
])
```

but it has no effect and XCode complains that I cannot satisfy constarints.

Comment: Please take a look at the edited answer and lemme know if it helps

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Save the reference to constraint as

```
let topConstraint = topBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 50)
```

Later activate it by using

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([topConstraint])
```

Finally, when you need to remove the constant simply say

```
button.removeConstraint(topConstraint)
```

And then add the new constraint as

```
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
  topBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view2.topAnchor, constant: 50)
])
button.layoutIfNeeded()
```

about the usage of button.layoutIfNeeded please refer to comment below by [UpHoldoerOfTruth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8111753/upholderoftruth)

Thats it. Hope it helps

Comment: If you only have one constraint you can just do `topConstraint.isActive = true`.  The `layoutIfNeeded` is only required if you want to update to take place immediately (say for an animation) otherwise you can leave it out for the system to decide when to update the layout.  Also remember you should deactivate constraints before activating others.

Comment: @upholderoftruth : I updated my answer to deactivate the constraint as you mentioned, I agree with your point on layoutIfNeeded, as I am not really sure as to whats OP doing with the constraint as a safe side I added it :)

Comment: It helps.. thank you. What is the difference between `remove` and `deactivate` constraint?

Comment: @martin-mickey : The only difference I know is when you call remove the constraint is actually removed, so if you iterate over the constraints on a view after calling remove you actually see the constraint being removed where as with deactivate constraints still there just that its isActive is turned off. Basically they both should do the job in this case, but because you weren't passing the reference to the already applied constraint to deactivate it wasn't deactivating your constraint :) Hope this helps

Comment: @martin-mickey : What I mean is NSLayoutConstraint.deactivate([
  topBtn.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: self.view.topAnchor, constant: 50)
]) will create a new constraint and wont refer to the same constraint you applied in previous statement, what you need is to deactivate the existing constraint so you need to save and pass the reference to previously applied constraint